# Не получается экспортировать класс

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Пишу для себя простую обертку над fetch. По задумке, должен быть класс `Call` c двумя статичными методами - `get` и `post`.

Пробовал писать вот так:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

class Call {
  static async get(url, params = {}) {
    ...
  }
  static async post(url, params = {}) {
    ...
  }
}

module.export = Call;
```

И вот так:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.export = {
  get: async (url, params = {}) => {
    ...
  },
  post: async (url, params = {}) => {
    ...
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь использовать:

```
const Call = require('./utils/call');
console.log(Call.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
```

И получаю:

```
console.log(Call.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
                 ^

TypeError: Call.get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ilabizunov/Events/server/parser/parser.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для экспорта чего-либо из модуля действительно можно использовать свойство [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

Проблема в том, что вы написали это свойство с очепяткой (потеряли `s` на конце).